# Python Writing to Excel Iteratively

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to make my code write to cells `A1`, `A2`, `A3` and `A4` in Excel. However, when I use it, I get this error message

> Invalid Cell coordinates (A)

'A' stays constant but 'i' changes with each repetition. How would I fix the problem on line 27? I want to make Python accept "A" as a column reference.

This was line 27:

```
ws.cell('A',i).value =  "The price of", symbolslist[i], " is ", price"
```

and my entire Python script:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

import urllib
import re

from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter

wb = Workbook()

dest_filename = r'empty_book.xlsx'

ws = wb.create_sheet()

ws.title = 'Stocks'
symbolslist = ["aapl","spy","goog","nflx"] 

i=0
while i<len(symbolslist):
    #counts each object as 1 in the list
    url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s="+symbolslist[i]+"&q1=1"
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_'+symbolslist[i]+'">(.+?)</span>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    price = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
    print "The price of", symbolslist[i], " is ", price 
    ws.cell(1,i+1).value =  "The price of" + symbolslist[i] + " is " + price 
    i+=1


wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
```

I am also using this as a [reference](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html), from openpyxl.

Comment: `'A' + str(i) == 'A1'`

Comment: Where do I plug that in? Any why would I want "Ai" to be A1 all the time?

Comment: I plugged it in like this...

    ws.cell('A' + str(i) == 'A1').value =  "The price of", symbolslist[i], " is ", price

And I get this error message below.

You have to provide a value either for 'coordinate' of for 'row' * and* 'column'.

Comment: I get a new error saying "There is no row "A0". However, if I change i to 1, I get a different set of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT***

Your i=0 on the first pass but there is no zero column.  Also, I think the cell is looking for row index which is a number not a character 'A'.

```
ws.cell(1,i+1).value =  "The price of" + symbolslist[i] + " is " + price
```

Comment: I replaced line 27 with that and I have Powershell stalling. Does the code work for you?

Comment: Odd, now it is saying 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'.

Comment: This is what I have for the line.

`code`
ws.cell(1,i+1).value = "The price of"+ symbolslist[i]+ " is "+ "price"
`code`

However, I still get the'int' object has no attribute 'replace' error.

Comment: Does my previous comment make sense to you?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I 'm using notepad++. I get this error message on line 27 

``ws.cell(1,i+1).value =  "The price of" + symbolslist[i] + " is " + price`` 

Type Error: Cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects. I'm going to go google it.

Comment: It didn't work, I try that previously too :( Good idea though.

Comment: Good thinking..it says 'int' object has no attributes 'replace'. When I used this line...``ws.cell(1,i+1).value =  "5"``

Great idea.

Comment: Okay, maybe it see's i+1 as a string because it's python.  Try adding a new variable int b = i+1 instead: ws.cell(1,b).value

Answer (score 0):

It is the use of ws.cell().value that is not correct. I had the error saying 'int' object has no attribute 'replace', but after I changed the line to the following, the error dispappeared:
    ws.cell(row=1,column=i+1).value =  "The price of" + str(symbolslist[i]) + " is " +     str(price)

By the way, I am using Python 2.7 and the latest version of openpyxl